# How to remove this HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'd like to remove the following HTML:

```
<a href="" class="css-button">Buy It</a>
```

This HTML is added dynamically (not by me).

How is this done in jquery?  Or is it better done in AngularJS?

Comment: Are there other elements with that class? If so removal will depend on the hierarchy/form of its parent elements, which you will need to show.

Comment: It depends on your project, but usually you'd add an `ng-hide="..."` attribute to the element with the condition when to hide it.

Comment: I think two critical questions were missed: Are there other "css-button"s in the layout? and Is href really empty or does it have a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would solve this by using css..

```
.css-button {display: none !important}
```

since it is added dynamically you would need a trigger function or search repedetly for that special container -> slows down the page

*//EDIT with jQuery if necessary*

if you really want to do it with jquery, is it always a certain container where the button appears? you could do something like this:

```
function removeButton() {
    $('.css-button').remove();
}

// Listen DOM changes
$('.theContainer').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", removeButton);
```

see here: http://davidwalsh.name/dom-events-javascript

Comment: Awesome and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.remove()`:

```
$('.css-button').remove();
```

Comment: Can't do that.  I've updated the OP.  The code is inserted dynamically by a Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to find the button, keep in mind that is a string search:

```
$( "a:contains('Buy It')" ).remove()
```

Comment: Please see revised OP.  I'll need to search for this since it is added dynamically.  I think you posted just after I updated the OP.